# How to display all the contents from a particular folder when I clicked on that folder name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to display all images from a particular folder when I clicked on that folder name. Here I tried to display list of folder structure and images separatly but i want to display the images when folder name is clicked

List of Files :

```
 <li id="li1"><a href=""><?php
 $root = 'images/';
 listFolderFiles($root); ?></a> 
</li>

<?php 
 function listFolderFiles($dir){
 $ffs = scandir($dir);

  unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
  unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);
  if (count($ffs) < 1)
    return;
 echo '<ol>';
 foreach($ffs as $ff){
    echo '<li>'.$ff;
    if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
    echo '</li>';
 }
 echo '</ol>';
 }
 ?>
```

List of images:

```
<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $image = $files[$i];
    $supported_file = array(
            'gif',
            'jpg',
            'jpeg',
            'png'
    );

    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
        echo basename($image)."<br />"; echo $image."<br />";
        echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" width="100px" 
         height="100px" />';
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: are your images placed on that folder, can you post the output of the two scripts, it will be helpful if you want to get help

Comment: yes, I am unable to post screenshot in comment, i have main folder images and subfolders fold1, fold2 like that i want to display images from fold1 or 2 ehwn i clicked on fold1 or 2. please let me know what to do?

Comment: How is this related to `javascript`, `jquery` or `ajax`??

Comment: You want to achieve something, thats okay. But what exactly is not working with the given code?

Comment: given code is working fine i want to relate both by adding click function by using jquery or javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to make each folder clickable like this for example:

```
<a href="listimages.php?dir=fold1">fold1</a>
<a href="listimages.php?dir=fold2">fold2</a>
<a href="listimages.php?dir=fold3">fold3</a>
```

then use this code for `listimages.php`:

```
<?php
   $files = glob("images/".$_GET['dir']."/*.*");
   for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
   {
    $image = $files[$i];
    $supported_file = array(
            'gif',
            'jpg',
            'jpeg',
            'png'
     );

     $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
     if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
        echo basename($image)."<br />"; echo $image."<br />";
         echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" width="100px" 
         height="100px" />';
        } else {
            continue;
        }
      }
   ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but as i am getting folders list from the directory i do not know how many folders will be there in future can i make it as dynamic? means which ever folders loaded from the directory are clicked and open the contents related to that folder. how to achieve it?

Comment: I think on this part your code is already dynamic, it will always list the directories, please do some couple of testing folders, and let me know if it is working fine.

Comment: It's not working, even though listing of folders is dynamic i want click each and every folder with only one '<a href>' not for evry folder name which ever displaying because n number of sub-folders will be there for each main folder.  and want to display images after clicking. How to make retrieved folders to be clickable and display the contents?